# Battery discharge

Tags: battery

My battery discharges when the ipad Air 2 I own is plugged into the wall for charging and I am using the unit during the course of the day for business. Thus, I am supposed to be charging from the cable, but instead it is discharging as I use my ipad Air 2, as if it is not plugged in for a charge.
Is this normal?  Or is there a setting which is incorrect?
Thanx for the assistance.

Comment: Are you using the charger that came with? Or a replacement?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not normal. If you plug another iOS device in using the power brick and Lightning cable, will it charge? Most likely, it is a faulty Lightning cable. A MFi replacement can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K4VQZCM), much cheaper than from the Apple Store. Make sure, if you are not original Lightning cable, that you are using one that is Made for iPhone (MFi). The ones you can buy at Walgreens do not meet Apple standards.